# How do I remove an row from an array based on specific condition in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, filtering

I'm having an array named **userList** and get it get filled by pushing some data in to it via a loop...
like this

```
userList.push({
  userProfileID : dataEntry.UserProfileID ,
  isAgent       : dataEntry.isAgent       ,
  firstName     : dataEntry.firstName     ,
  roleNames     : dataEntry.roleNames
})
```

and the output will be like this and 100 more records

```
0: Object {userProfileID: "68670", isAgent: false, firstName: "ARSDEO", roleNames:"Deo Role"}
1: Object {userProfileID: "68672", isAgent: false, firstName: "ARSBM101", roleNames:"BM Role"}
2:.......
3:.......
```

Here I want to remove the entry which has **roleNames  = 'BM role'**  in userList array

I tried this :

```
userList = userList.filter(item => userList.roleNames == 'BM Role');
```

but I get no record in array.
Please advice...

Comment: *filter* doesn't remove anything, it creates a new array. To remove an element, use *splice*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Almost.

You want to check if the property `rolesNames` on *`item`* *doesn't equal* "BM Role" (ie you want to filter those out)

```
const newList = userList.filter(item => item.roleNames !== 'BM Role');
```

Note: `filter`, like the other functional array methods `map` and `reduce`, doesn't mutate the array, it returns a *new* array with only those elements that match the condition in the callback.

Answer (score 3):

Try to check if roleNames `isn't equal` to `'Bm Role'`.

```js
userList = userList.filter((user) => {
    return user.roleNames !== 'BM role';
})
```

**BTW** `filter()` method creates a copy of original array.

But if you want to delete directly from original array, I suggest to you use `splice()` method:

```js
for(let i = 0; i < userList.length; i++){ 
   if (userList[i].roleNames === 'BM Role') {
      userList.splice(i, 1); 
      i--;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

IF the question is about **removing** elements fron userList:

```js
var userList = 
[ { userProfileID: '68670', isAgent: false, firstName: 'ARSDEO', roleNames: 'Deo Role' } 
, { userProfileID: '68672', isAgent: false, firstName: 'aaaaaa', roleNames: 'aaa Role' } 
, { userProfileID: '68674', isAgent: false, firstName: 'bbbbbb', roleNames: 'BM Role'  } 
, { userProfileID: '68676', isAgent: false, firstName: 'cccccc', roleNames: 'BM Role'  } 
, { userProfileID: '68678', isAgent: false, firstName: 'dddddd', roleNames: 'bbb Role' } 
] 
  

for (let i=userList.length;i--;)  // start from end to zero
{
  if (userList[i].roleNames==='BM Role') { userList.splice(i, 1) }
}

for (let elm of userList ) { console.log( JSON.stringify(elm) )  }
```

Answer (score 1):

your filter is not correct:

```
userList = userList.filter(item => item.roleNames != 'BM Role');
```

the item variable is what you are checking against. On each filter call a new item is passed to the function, and this is what is being evaluated

Comment: The OP wants a filtered list of items that _don't_ contain BM role.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `item.roleNames` instead of `userList.roleNames`, since `roleNames` is a part of the specific object/item in the array and not the array itself.
Additionally you should probably use `item.roleNames != 'BM Role'`, because filter returns an array that contains the matching items, and you want to remove those that match.